# How to access DOM from previous sibling in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get id(id 1) name of a div from a div(class 2) in the next line. When I use previousSibling, it worked on google chrome but not on safari since safari catches the area between divs as "#text".
In my code, id name is very unique and there are many different id name so I do not want to find by id name.
Is there any good way to access previous sibling??

```
<div id="parent">
 <div id="1">
  <div class="1-1"></div>
  <div class="1-2"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I use previousSibling, it worked on google chrome but not on safari since safari catches the area between divs as "#text".

It works. It just doesn't do what you want it to do. It returns sibling [`Node`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node). In this case a *TextNode*.

What you are looking for is an [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element), a specific subclass of Node. For that there's the [`.previousElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/previousElementSibling) property.

Inspecting a DOM node with the debugger and then looking up the documentation on the available properties is a good way to find such things.